# Subgroup properties in polynomial rings (from AKS-Test correctness proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, prime-numbers

In a lecture we showed the correctness of the AKS-test and therefor defined the following:

> $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb F} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z} \newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$
> We have a polynomial $f(X) =X^r-1$ and its splitting field $\F$ over $\F_p=\Z/ p\Z$ for a primedivisor $p$ of $n \in \N$. Then it holds true that:
> $$f(X)=\prod_{i=1}^{r}(X-\alpha_i)\;\text{ with }\alpha_i\in \F$$
>
> Let $r\in \{\lceil (\log(n)^2\rceil+1,\ldots, \lfloor(\log(n))^5\rfloor\}$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(r,n)=1$ and $\operatorname{ord}_r(n)>(\log(n))^2$, where we define $\operatorname{ord}_r(n)$ as follows: $$\operatorname{ord}_r(n) := \min\{i\mid i\geq 1\land n^i\equiv 1\bmod r\}$$
>
> Further, let $f'(X)=rX^{r-1}$ be the derivation of $f(X)$ and it holds true that $\forall i: f'(\alpha_i)\not=0$, since $r$ is not a divisor of $n$ (definition) and therefore it is also not a divisor of $p$. Thats why $r\not\equiv 0\bmod p$ is true. Hence, that we know that all $\alpha_i$ are single zeros of $f$. We now set:
> $$U=\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_r\}\subseteq\F^\ast$$
>
> This subgroup is of order $r$, since all $\alpha_i$ are different to each other. Further it is a finite and cyclic subgroup of $F^\ast$ with $\varphi(r)$ different generators.

##### Question

I'm not understanding how $U$ is a subgroup. I know the neutral element of $U$ ($e_U  = 1$), but the existence of the inverse elements and that $U$ is closed, isn't clear to me. Can someone explain to me why $U$ is a subgroup? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since $|U|$ is finite, it suffices to show that $\varnothing \neq U\subseteq \Bbb F^*$ and that $U$ is closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U = \{\alpha \in \mathbb{F} : \alpha^r = 1\}$ ($\alpha \in U$ if and only if $\alpha^r = 1$). So, for example, if $\alpha \in U$ then $\alpha^{-1} \in U$ because $(\alpha^{-1})^r = (\alpha^r)^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: How do we know that $(\alpha^{-1})^r =(\alpha^{r})^{-1}$ holds true in $U$? Is that generally true in groups?

Comment: @Algebruh Because $(\alpha^r) \cdot (\alpha^{-1})^r = 1$ so they're inverses of each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Guess that was too much today, if I can't see that anymore :D